# iOS Distribution Certificate expiring. what are my options?

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution

My Current Distribution Certificate expired today. That means both my AdHoc and AppStore provisioning profiles expired as well.

I have 2 apps that have already been submitted to Apple review; 1 is waiting for review, the other is 'in review'.

It doesn't seem like i can generate a new Distribution Certificate as there is no option for it. Only revoke or download. I assume if I revoke it, i can then create a new Certificate. Is that correct? (1)

and (2), if I do revoke it, what will happen to my existing apps that are in review. Will they get thrown out of the queue? That wouldn't be nice, especially since i have time constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Yes, create a new certificate with a new expiration date.
(2) Nothing, once an app is signed, the signature stays in effect until its expiration date, even if you delete the certificate or provisioning profile from the Portal later on.

Comment: TY that did it for me! It's hard to believe that that's the way it works. First you have to REVOKE your existing cert. Then you create a new one. It's actually a matter of a few minutes but it's still weird.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes. This is correct.
(2) The documentation doesn't say anything about the review queue. It does say that any apps in the store are unaffected, but you won't be able to submit new ones, so you're probably fine.

https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/