# iOS distribution certificate is expiring soon. What are the next steps?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I found several topics about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947595/what-will-happen-if-ios-distribution-certificate-expired) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404832/ios-distribution-certificate-expiring-what-are-my-options) and I have additional questions. My distribution certificate will expire soon (in several days). From the documentation and related posts I can assume:

1. My already published at the apple store apps will not be affected.
2. My push certificates will not be affected and pushed apps will continue to send/receive pushes
3. I need to re-generate the distribution certificate and provisioning profile if I want to publish an app update (or another app)

Here my questions:

1. The main and most annoying question is should I re-generate this
   certificate EVERY year? (it is valid for only 1 year)
2. Should I re-generate distribution certificate and provisioning profile ONLY or
   I should re-create AppId as well?
3. If AppId is affected then should I re-generate push-certificates which are already in use by our back-end system (and as a result re-publish back-end with the new    certificate)?
4. After the expiration date can I REVOKE and DELETE all the certificates from the apple store certificate management center because there is no use of them?

Could anybody confirm my suggestions and clarify my questions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can revoke and then re-ask a new certificate.
You then have to update the provisionning profiles with the new certificat, and it's ready ;)

Trust me, I did it much times.

Comment: first time is always scary ) could you confirm that no changes to appid should be made?

Comment: Don't touch the AppId. Only care about the certificate, and , if requested, the provisionning profile.